# Video as a background to the site?

Tags: html, video, background

I have several questions.
I will be working over a site soon and I've seen a site with quite a nice background type that I have no ideea how it's made. I mean I have an ideea, but Im not so sure.
Here is the site Im talking about:
https://www.freeplus.co.jp/en
Im guessing It's some kind of autoplaying video with no sound? Bigger gifs?

Comment: Looks to be MP4s. as someone with a poor internet connection, please don't do it!

Comment: Have you read the source code of that page? Inspected the element? Tried something?

Comment: I did, but I can seem to find it. Still new to HTML

Comment: The thing that I am working on its more like a "homework", rather than a fully working site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add just a video like;

```
    <video class="fullscreen" autoplay loop muted>   
        <source src="http://somesiteurl/videoname.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
    </video>
```

,then add other things with transparent background and proper position adjustments.

Comment: That seems to be it, I'll look for the video. Thanks!